# How to parse "8/31/2017 15:45:32" to a DateTime object

Tags: ruby, datetime

I tried all sorts of combinations and the one that seems like it ought to work is:

```
DateTime.strptime "8/31/2017 15:45:32", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"
```

and

```
DateTime.parse "8/31/2017 15:45:32"
```

But they don't work and in fact I can't find the magical incantation to parse it.

Comment: What do you mean by “don’t work”? Is an exception raised? If so, what is the error message? Did you execute `require ‘date’`. (Please show that.) To format blocks of code in your question indent at least 4 spaces or (easier) select the code and click on the `{}` icon. (Please edit to do that.) To format code embedded in text surrounded it with back-ticks (\`).

Comment: Note that `parse` can easily give misleading results: `Date.parse 'I will do it, maybe' => #<Date: 2019-05-01 ((2458605j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse a year with century use `%Y` instead of `%y`. `%y` only matches years without a centure – like `8/31/17` in your example.

```
 DateTime.strptime "8/31/2017 15:45:32", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"
 #=> #<DateTime: 2017-08-31T15:45:32+00:00 ((2457997j,56732s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Find the formating directives in the docs: [`DateTime.strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) Or use the great [strftime.net](http://strftime.net) webpage to discover formats.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know about `strftime.net`.